# React native refs is undefined in when reading Text Input ref in Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have several components in my application each with a textInput field. As each textInput is submit then I want it to focus on the next component's textInput field. Instead my function in the parent component says:

`undefined is not an object (evaluating'_this.refs[nextField].focus')`

This is my code:

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component {
....
render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
         <View style={{padding:20}}>
             <One
                 ...
                 onSubmitEditing={this.focusNextField("2")} />

              <TWO
                 .../>
    )
  }
focusNextField = (nextField) => {
    alert(nextField)
    this.refs[nextField].focus()
 }
}

export default class One extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
             <View style={{paddingBottom:5}}>
                <TextInput
                 ref="1"
                 style={{height:60,paddingLeft:20}}
                 placeholder="Enter your name"
                 onSubmitEditing={this.props.onSubmitEditing} />
             </View>
     )
  }
}


export default class Two extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <View style={{paddingBottom:5}}>
               <TextInput
               ref="2"
               keyboardType="phone-pad"
               style={{height:60,paddingLeft:20}}
               placeholder="Enter your age" />
          </View>
      )
   }
}
```

How can you use `refs`from different components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access refs of another component you need to access that component as a ref too. For example `this.refs[nextField].refs[childref]`. In this way you can travel down the tree
    In order to access a DOM element, you should use `React.findDOMNode()`

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component {
....
render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
         <View style={{padding:20}}>
             <One
                 ...
                 onSubmitEditing={this.focusNextField.bind(this, "two","2")} />

              <TWO ref="two"
                 .../>
    )
  }
focusNextField = (nextField, childref) => {
    alert(nextField)
    React.findDOMNode(this.refs[nextField].refs[childref]).focus();
 }
}

export default class One extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
             <View style={{paddingBottom:5}}>
                <TextInput
                 ref="1"
                 style={{height:60,paddingLeft:20}}
                 placeholder="Enter your name"
                 onSubmitEditing={this.props.onSubmitEditing} />
             </View>
     )
  }
}


export default class Two extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <View style={{paddingBottom:5}}>
               <TextInput
               ref="2"
               keyboardType="phone-pad"
               style={{height:60,paddingLeft:20}}
               placeholder="Enter your age" />
          </View>
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still gives me an error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating'_this.refs[nextField].refs)`

Comment: one thing try and console log in your focusNextField function and see if you are getting the parameters. my guess is that we need to bind them too

Comment: try the updated code, which includes a binding param

Comment: That has worked but it is very slow. in entering a text field and pressing return. Generall it's slowed the whole app down

Comment: I dont know how it slows the performance, but this is the way to do it. This method works fine for my case

Comment: Thanks the reason for the slow down was due to remote debugging.